# Installing npm packages listing many errors using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I am working on Windows, using NodeJS method, firstly, I found difficulty in making node_modules folder even after writing `npm install` command. Secondly, there is a list of errors if I install any of the npm packages. Similarly, I installed express through command `npm install express` and this is what I got.

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm ERR! code EBADF
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! errno -4083
npm ERR! EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
```

Kindly assist me in resolving these issues!

Comment: provide your package.json file please

Answer (score -1):

If you are experiencing difficulties with the `node_modules` folder not being created or encountering errors while installing npm packages in a Windows environment, you can try the following steps to resolve the issues:

1. Difficulty in creating the node_modules folder:

   - Make sure you are running the `npm install` command in the root directory of your project where the `package.json` file is located.
   - Check for any error messages displayed in the console when running `npm install`. If there are errors, please provide those error messages for further investigation.
2. Errors when installing npm packages:
   The warnings you mentioned (`TAR_ENTRY_ERROR` and `EBADF`) are related to the `tar` package used by npm to extract and manage package archives. To troubleshoot this:

   - Ensure that you have the latest version of Node.js installed on your system.
   - Clear the npm cache by running `npm cache clean --force`.
   - Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file (if it exists) in your project directory.
   - Run `npm install` again to reinstall the packages.

If you are still encountering errors, please provide the complete error messages so that we can assist you further.

Regarding the specific error you mentioned while installing Express (`npm ERR! code EBADF`), it indicates a "bad file descriptor" error. To troubleshoot this:

- Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to read and write files in the project directory.
- Close any other programs that may be using or locking the files in your project directory.
- Run the Command Prompt or your terminal as an administrator and try running the `npm install` command again.

If the error persists, please provide the complete error message, including any additional information, to help us investigate further.